# How do you know which registers are being written and read?

Tags: assembly, binary, mips, machine-code, circuit

I know this isn't a site for hardware, but I feel like if I understand this it'll help with my MIPS Assembly coding overall. Thanks.

The pipelined MIPS processor is running the following program.

Which registers are being written, and which are being read on the fifth cycle?

```
addi $s1, $s2, 5
sub $t0, $t1, $t2
lw $t3, 15($s1)
sw $t5, 72($t0)
or $t2, $s4, $s5
```

So I understand what the code is doing but how can I tell which registers are being written and which are being read on the fifth cycle?

Comment: The typical MIPS pipeline has 5 stages, as I hope you know. Thus the 5th cycle is actually going to be the write-back for the first instruction, that is `$s1` is going to be written. In that same clock, the 3rd instruction is in the `EX` stage, which assuming forwarding, also reads the same `$s1` to use as address.